# Quering and writing to a file : errorcode 28

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting this error when I try to query the database and write results to a file.
It never occured before.

> java.sql.SQLException: Error writing
>   file '/tmp/MYwADPLw' (Errcode: 28)
>
> at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3170)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3099)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1169)
>     at DBase.connect(DBase.java:58)
>   // this is where i call executequery
>     at
>   automateExport.main(automateExport.java:11)
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   automateExport.main(automateExport.java:13)
>   // main class with db connection

The resultset I am expecting is very large.
I never had this problem when I was querying for a smaller resultset.
Could it be space issues? I have 117 gb on my disc. But I am expecting a max of 1gb text data. 
Any solutions???

My Code:

```
 public Connection connect(String db_connect_str,String db_userid, String db_password) {
        Connection conn;
        Statement stmt;
        String query;
     // inputfile - csv
        String input = "inputfile.txt";
        try {
         // to bifurcate heap memory error   
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_str,db_userid, db_password);
            stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,  
                    java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE); 

            query = "SELECT  r.name, r.network , r.namestring, i.name, i.description "+
            " , r.rid  , i.id, d.dtime ,d.ifInOctets , d.ifOutOctets , FROM_UNIXTIME(d.dtime)"+
            " FROM router AS r INNER JOIN interface AS i ON r.rid = i.rid " +
            "INNER JOIN  1278993600_1_60 AS d ON i.id = d.id " +
            "AND dtime BETWEEN " +startTime+ " AND "+ endTime +" WHERE r.network = 'ITPN'" +
                    "AND i.status = 'active' ORDER BY i.id, d.dtime";

            BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(input));            
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); 
            String idescp = null;
            // writing to file
            while (rs.next()) {
              if(rs.getString("description").equals(null)){
                  System.out.println("description" +rs.getString("description") );
                  idescp = "NA";
                  System.out.println("idescp :" +idescp + ":");
              }else{
                  idescp = rs.getString("description");
              }
              fw.write(rs.getString(1)+","+ rs.getString("rid")+","+ rs.getString("id") + "," +idescp+","
                      +rs.getString("dtime")+ "," +rs.getString("ifInOctets")+ "," + 
                      rs.getString("ifOutOctets") + ","+ rs.getString(11)+NL); 
            }

            fw.close();
            rs.close() ;
            stmt.close() ;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            conn = null;
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what your automateExport main method looks like?

Comment: public class automateExport { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{ 

DBase db = new DBase();
 
Connection conn = db.connect( "jdbc:mysql://comm.comng..com/perf","bread", "nm36"); conn.close();
 }
 }

Comment: works perfect for a smaller resultset of data. gives above error for a larger resultset.

Comment: there is not result set in the sample of code you writed

Comment: a 1gb+ resultset is huge and will comsume a bunch of server resources for a long time. can't you call a stored proc that select... into outfile server side and then transfer the data file and process it locally ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the database runs out of temp space on the file. I would check if ot the path given, the account the database is running on has the right and the space to write some data.

Comment: but i am running it and writing it on my machine. file gets created in my workspace

Comment: And the MySQL engine is started with your account? Is there enough free space on the drive mentioned in the error message?

Comment: I have no idea which drive this could be:  '/tmp/MYwADPLw' 
I am writing on my machine only. Just querying db for the data.

Comment: could it be because of the complex query?? if i break the query down to 2 parts would that help???

Comment: @jillika So the database is running on a server different from your machine? Who is administering that server? Maybe you should contact her/him and have them do the space check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My machine runs out of memory.  Your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will write large resultsets to disk for streaming. The database server's /tmp folder is likely filling up as @Frank suggests.